# Python 3 tkinter treeview get NAME of selected item

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, selected

So basically I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgjPL.jpg) tree:

And I want to have the name of the item selected back by pressing the "aggiungi" button.
For example when I select Pomodori and then press the button I want "Pomodori" back as string, If I select Frutta I want "Frutta" and so on...
I tried with get.children and then tree.set() but I cant get that to work.
How do I do that?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

_root = Tk()
_root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

_F_shopItems = Frame(_root)
_F_shopItems.pack(side="left")

_F_treeview = Frame(_root)
_F_treeview.pack(side="left")

_F_bottom = Frame(_root)
_F_bottom.pack(side="bottom")

# ------------------------
# Treeview
_T_listaProd = ttk.Treeview(_F_treeview, height=10)
_T_listaProd.column("#0", width=165)
_T_listaProd.heading("#0", text="Prodotti")
_T_listaProd.config(columns="Prezzi")
_T_listaProd.column("Prezzi", width=75, anchor="center")
_T_listaProd.heading("Prezzi", text="Prezzi (€/Kg)")
_T_listaProd.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Categorie di prodotti
_T_listaProd.insert('', '0', 'Verdura', text='Verdura')
_T_listaProd.insert('', '1', 'Frutta', text='Frutta')
_T_listaProd.insert('', '2', 'Carne', text='Carne')
_T_listaProd.insert('', '3', 'Dolci', text='Dolci')

# Verdura
_T_listaProd.insert('Verdura', 'end', 'V1', text='Insalata Gentile')
_T_listaProd.set("V1", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Verdura', 'end', 'V2', text='Cipolla Bianca')
_T_listaProd.set("V2", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Verdura', 'end', 'V3', text='Radicchio')
_T_listaProd.set("V3", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Verdura', 'end', 'V4', text='Pomodori')
_T_listaProd.set("V4", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Verdura', 'end', 'V5', text='Peperoni')
_T_listaProd.set("V5", "Prezzi", "0,98")

# Frutta
_T_listaProd.insert('Frutta', 'end', 'F1', text='Mele rosse')
_T_listaProd.set("F1", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Frutta', 'end', 'F2', text='Ciliege')
_T_listaProd.set("F2", "Prezzi", "0,98")

# Dolci
_T_listaProd.insert('Dolci', 'end', 'D1', text='Crostata (Marmellata)')
_T_listaProd.set("D1", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Dolci', 'end', 'D2', text='Nutella')
_T_listaProd.set("D2", "Prezzi", "0,98")

# Carne
_T_listaProd.insert('Carne', 'end', 'C1', text='Braciola di Maiale')
_T_listaProd.set("C1", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Carne', 'end', 'C2', text='Pancetta')
_T_listaProd.set("C2", "Prezzi", "0,98")
_T_listaProd.insert('Carne', 'end', 'C3', text='Salame')
_T_listaProd.set("C3", "Prezzi", "0,98")

# Scrollbar
_S_listaProd = Scrollbar(_F_treeview, orient=VERTICAL, command=_T_listaProd.yview)
_S_listaProd.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
_T_listaProd.config(yscrollcommand=_S_listaProd.set)
# ------------------------
_T_listaProd.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', #To do#)



_B_addItem = Button(_F_bottom, text="aggiungi", command = #To do#)
_B_addItem.pack(side="bottom") 

_main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849035/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-selected-treeview-item/34855093

Answer (score 3):

Virtual event `<<TreeviewSelect>>` and method `ttk.Treeview.selection` might be what you need,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.tree.pack()

        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", tk.END, text="item %s" % i)

        self.tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.on_select)

        self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="test", command=self.print_selected)

        self.button.pack()
        self.selected = []

    def on_select(self, event):
        self.selected = event.widget.selection()

    def print_selected(self):
        for idx in self.selected:
            print(self.tree.item(idx)['text'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```